# Customized RuntimeException not catching java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, exception, runtimeexception

anyone can tell why the catch close is ducking (not catching) the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ? The catch block only works with no customized Exception.

```
class MyException extends RuntimeException {

    public MyException(String msg) {

        super(msg);
        System.out.println("caught in MyException2 constructor");
    }
}

public class CustomizedExceptionTester {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {
                doTest();
            } catch (MyException me) {

                System.out.println("caught in catch block");

                System.out.println(me);
            }
        }

        static void doTest() throws MyException {
            int[] array = new int[10];
            array[10] = 1000;
        }
    }
```

prints :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
    at oca.exceptions.InterfaceWithException.doTest(InterfaceWithException.java:32)
    at oca.exceptions.InterfaceWithException.main(InterfaceWithException.java:17)
```

Comment: The reason could be that runtimeException is a non-checked exeption and that runtimeExceptions are supposed to terminate the thread without being caught.

Comment: Runtime exceptions can be caught. The problem here is that you're specifying a subclass of `RuntimeException`. That doesn't mean that every subclass of `RuntimeException` will be caught - only the type specified will be caught.

Comment: This is precisely what wanted to know. Thank you.

Comment: cool! I undeleted my answer - I've gone into greater detail (it's essentially an expanded version of my comment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you expect it to? You've got `MyException` in the catch block; it will only catch exceptions of that type. Even though both `MyException` and `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` extend `RuntimeException`, it doesn't mean that *all* subclasses of `RuntimeException` should be caught when you specify *any* subclass; only the type specified will be caught.

Think of it this way. Suppose I have "four-sided shape", "rectangle", and "rhombus". If I say "catch any rectangles I throw you", would you catch a rhombus? But if I said "catch any four-sided shape I throw you", you would catch both regardless.

Comment: I don't expect this code to handle exceptions this way. It's a OCA 1Z0 803 tricky type of question. Just preparing. Thanks a lot for replying.

Answer (score 2):

You are saying that `doTest()` can throw `MyException` which is fine whether it does or not. Trying to access an array index out of bounds does not throw `MyException`, it throws `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Java will not catch an exception that is not being thrown. If you want your custom exception code to run to need to explicitly throw it.

```
try {
    array[10] = 1000;
} catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    throw new MyException(e.getMessage());
}
```

This situation does not really benefit from this so you could move your exeption code to inside the catch block or extract it to a separate method.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I imagined RuntimeException with a switch() {case : } method that would refine the search for me.